# Radial atomic force

Tags: forces, particle-physics, atomic-physics

Recently I read an article that discussed the extremes in physics and chemistry, and what might happen if they were somehow possible. one of such extremes caught my attention in particular, which proposes the possibility of applying a force radially inward on an atom, compressing it smaller and smaller until it reached that critical point and became "impossibly" dense.

However my question is: what would happen if that force were reversed? So instead of forcing the atom inward to become more dense, have a force that is applied outward Radially to create some sort of expansion or decrease in density. Could such a force even exist? And if so what affects would it have on an Atom? A molecule? And would the speed at which this force is applied render different results?